# Django template - showing data from two models

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i'd like to have simple site on which i can see status of cars.
Let's assume that i have two tables:
cars :

```
|id|car |mileage| insurance|
----------------------------
| 1|ford| 123456|23-06-2015|
| 2|fiat| 654321|23-06-2015|
```

and a second one, faults :

```
|id|car_id|description|
----------------------------
| 1|     1|stop ligths doesn't work
| 2|     1|power steer needs refill
| 3|     2|etc
| 4|     2|etc
```

What i want to have on my website table like that :

```
|            |        mileage|       insurance|
|            |---------------------------------
|            |{{car.mileage}}|{{car.insurance}}
| {{car.car}}|---------------------------------
|            |            Faults
|            |---------------------------------
|            | << list of faults for current {{car.id}}>>
-------------------------------------------------------
<<next car>>
```

I know how to get simple table, but the problem for me is second forloop (?) for faults per current car. How should i set up querysets in views and forloops in template ?
My actual code is sligthly different than example:

```
models
class Pojazdy(models.Model):
 id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 pojazd=models.CharField(max_length=15) #car
 rejestracja=models.CharField(max_length=15)
 aktywny=models.BooleanField(default=True)
 def __unicode__(self):
     return self.pojazd

class Pojazdy_usterki(models.Model): #faults
 id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 pojazd=models.ForeignKey(Pojazdy)
 usterka=models.CharField(max_length=255) #faults
 przebieg=models.IntegerField()
 data=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
 zrobiona=models.BooleanField(default=False)


view 

I have some comparisons    

def index(request):
 pojazdy_qs=Pojazdy.objects.all().filter(aktywny__exact= True)
 for pojazd in pojazdy_qs:
    (...)
    # some operations
    (...)


 return render(request, 'auta_hist/index.html', {
     'pojazdy': pojazdy_qs,
 })
```

And a table from template :

```
        <table  width=100%>
        {% for pojazd in pojazdy %}
        <tr>
            (... some table))
        </tr>
                 <td>
                            <table border=1 width=100%>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Usterki  !!! FAULTS !!!</th>
                                </tr>

                                {% for ??? %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ ?? }} </td>
                                </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% empty %}
        <tr><td>Brak danych</td></tr>
        {% endfor%}

    </table>
```

---

With answer for the above part new problem occurred :
my faults model has boolean field, which stands for whether fault is repaired or not. I would like to display only filtered items, and what's more, i'd like to have this list as a quick preview of three lastly added.
Generally i would like to have item filtered and than displayed only few of them. Is there way to do this ? Rigth now i filter items with {% if .. %} but have no idea how to limit them and not list all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use set ! 
You want to get all Pojazdy_usterki of selected Pojazdy like this:

```
<table  width=100%>
    {% for pojazd in pojazdy %}
    <tr>
        (... some table))
    </tr>
             <td>
                        <table border=1 width=100%>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Usterki  !!! FAULTS !!!</th>
                            </tr>

                            {% for e in pojazdy_usterki_set.all %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ e.usterka }} </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% empty %}
    <tr><td>Brak danych</td></tr>
    {% endfor%}

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, i couldn;t figure it out :)

   {% for usterka in pojazd.pojazdy_usterki_set.all %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{usterka.usterka}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}

Worked for me :)